# Pop up Modal is not showing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a user control that I want to show in a pop up, I did as following but pop up is not showing at all

```
  <div id="Dialog" style="display:none;">
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpPan" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
       <ContentTemplate>
        <uc:Search runat="server" ID="uc_Find" ModePopup="true"/>
  </ContentTemplate>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        minHeight: 450,
        height: 680,
        title: 'Edit',
        width: 780,
          resizable: false,
          open: function (event, ui) {
              $(this).parent().appendTo($('form:first'));
          }
       });
     });
   </script>



this.Page.OpenDialog("Edit", "Dialog");
```

Comment: Is there any error in the browser's console?

Comment: @Shaharyar there is no errors, besides when I try to debug I see that it's reaching the page load of the user control

Comment: Are you trying to open it based on an action or as soon as the page loads?  if action try $("#Dialog").dialog({modal: true}); when the action occurs on the clientside (javascript).  otherwise if you want it to open right away when the page loads, try setting autoOpen to true.